# complex conjugate line integral

Tags: complex-analysis

i have $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$, $t\in[0,2\pi]$ and the line integral $\overline{\int_{\gamma} f(z)\>dz}$. It is to show that

$\overline{\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz}$=$-\int_{\gamma} \frac{\overline{f(z)}}{z^2} dz$.

If i start with $\overline{\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz}=\int_{\overline{\gamma}} \overline{f(\overline{z}} )dz=\int_0^{2\pi} \overline{f(\gamma(t)}*\overline{\gamma'}(t)=\int_0^{2\pi}\overline{f(\gamma(t))}*ie^{-it}$ i do not come to a solution and also do not see how i can change  something on the last term.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. What you did wrong is $\overline{\gamma'(t)} = ie^{-it}$. It should be
$\overline{\gamma'(t)} = \overline{ie^{it}}= -ie^{-it}$. Finally, from your last line,
$$
-\int_0^{2\pi}\overline{f(\gamma(t))}ie^{-it}dt = -\int_0^{2\pi}\overline{f(\gamma(t))}e^{-2it}\cdot ie^{it}dt = -\int_\gamma\overline{f(z)}\frac{1}{z^2}dz,
$$as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the path us the unit circle. So the path, and it's complex conjugate are the same path in terms if their elements.

Also note that points on the unit circle have modulus=1. For such Points, their reciprocal is also their conjugate.

$\bar{z}=1/z. d(\bar{z})=\frac{-dz}{z^2.}$

I forget what it is, but there's a relationship between f applied at z , f applied at $\bar{z}$, the conjugate if f at z and the conjugate if f applied at the conjugate if z.

I think that combo should get you what you need.